# No output when calling $scope.variable in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In the following angular program i just want to display numbers,but nothing is being displayed.Can someone please guide me where i am doing wrong?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
            myModule.controller('mycontroller', function ($scope) {
                $scope.numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
            }

            );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="mycontroller">
            <div ng-repeat="number in mumbers">
                {{number}}
            </div>
        </div>
             </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `numbers` spelled wrong in your `ng-repeat` -- change `mumbers` to `numbers`